# Spring Integration Test Naming Conventions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a rest controller for creating and getting employees. To test these endpoints I have two classes. In one I mock the service layer and do status code checks such as:

```
Mockito.when(employeeService.createEmployee(any(Employee.class))).then(returnsFirstArg());
this.employeeClient.createEmployee(this.testEmployee)
    .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

In the other I start up a docker postgres database and don't mock anything. These tests involve multiple endpoints e.g. "If I create an employee and then get all the employees, the created employee should be returned".

Both these classes create an application context - the first uses the `WebMvcTest` annotation, the second uses `SpringBootTest`. For this reason I see them both as integration tests.

So then what do I call these tests? I'm currently using `EmployeeControllerTest` and `EmployeeContorllerIT` (running IT with the failsafe plugin), but the name for the first is a little misleading because it's not really a unit test.

I was thinking of using `EmployeControllerMockedIT` for the first, but not convinced that's the right way to go.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any naming conventions, since anything other than *Test would require some kind of setup to run the test in your build. But why do you need two separate tests here? Can't you have a single test that just does everything, from doing a mocked http-invocation to business logic and database verification? It shouldn't be that difficult to change your existing SpringBootTest to use MockMVC.

Comment: Separate because in the the non-mocked test class a fresh postgres docker db is prepared for each test. Don't want that overhead for all of the tests that mock out the service layer.

Comment: Yes I could change the SpringBootTest class to use MockMvc. But that class is doing stuff I want a real DB for i.e. verifying all of the code works with the db as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mocking responses, I'd say its a unit test as you're testing the module of code in isolation from a network and 3rd party systems like a database.

If you're running a test against (real) 3rd party code/systems you don't control, its an integration (or functional) test.

Functional tests will invoke your service as if your system is a black-box where we don't know the internal details (vs. white-box where we know, and have access to change, the internals and invoke code as if we're making a method call rather than sending an HTTP request).

Functional tests may run against real/fake servers but there will typically be a running application waiting for requests. The point being here the responses are not "mocked", the request is made for real, from your code, to the third party code/system, and that system is expected to respond as the real server would.

We do not fake responding in functional tests but arbitrary responses may be provided from the real/fake server to simulate the data we expect to receive. It could be we write a fake HTTP service to "mock" a real API. It will provide the exact same type of responses over the network, and be invoked over the network. Or we could just spin up a dockerised database and send queries to it and receive responses from it. The database will be a real database-server, rather than a mocked response we pre-specified in code.

Functional tests (of a web service) will begin from outside your application and ensure requests are answered over the network layer. i.e. you'll be making an HTTP request to invoke the service.

Integration tests of a web service will invoke the service at an application level (not over the network layer) so you may call a `Controller` class directly or invoke some code that is supposed to connect/integrate with a database from within the application. Integration tests will test your code is integrated correctly with third party code/a library/a database. Your tests should alert you to any situation where if the 3rd party code (code/system you do not control) changes in such a way that your software would break.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I guess it's a bit confusing because for both cases I'm hitting the same REST endpoint and getting a response. It's just that in one I'm mocking the service layer + db and in the other I'm spinning up a real db to run the tests again. So yes, in this web context your distinction of unit test vs integration test based on what's mocked does make sense, I'll leave it as ```EmployeeControllerTest``` and ```EmployeeControllerIT```